# Toggle DIV and close the gap

Tags: jquery, css

This is a simplified version of something I want to achieve

I have a page that displays 3 div boxes

```
<div class="divd" id='div1' style="left:50px">>111</div>
<div class="divd" id='div2' style="left:150px">222</div>  
<div class="divd" id='div3' style="left:250px">333</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><input type="button"  id="tg" value="toggle"></p>
```

I am using Jquery to toggle the middle div

```
  $('#tg').click(function() { 
    $('#div2').toggle('slow', function() {
    });
  });
```

This all works as expected, But what I want to do is 'close the gap' left by hiding the div , so the end result is div1 and div3 next to each other Can this be done, any pointers or help much appreciated , thanks

```
.divd { 
position:absolute ; 
width: 50px;
height: 50px;   
top: 50px ;
left: 120px ; 
border: 1px solid black;
background-color:#999; 
border-radius:5px;  
z-index:200;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: By `next to each other` do you mean in the same line?

Comment: Which gap are you talking about ? It all looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/agpHB/

Comment: yes, the div height in my finished page is the height of my page

Comment: jQuery's toggle is same as show/hide or display: none/block. It should not leave gap.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/d7Fc7/

Comment: lowcase, Thats it !!, I have included the style for the divd class. What have I done wrong

Comment: Please see my answer. You can't use absolute positioning without some futher DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your elements are absolutely positioned, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/agpHB/1/

You need to not do that. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/agpHB/2/

```
.divd {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

<div class="divd" id="div1">111</div>
<div class="divd" id="div2">222</div>
<div class="divd" id="div3">333</div>
```

The float isn't even strictly necessary. If you must position absolutely, you'll need to slide element 3 to the position of element 2 at the same time that you do the toggle. It won't be nearly as simple.

UPDATE: To respond to your comment about additional elements, try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/agpHB/3/

Comment: This is a great solution but ultimately i want  444 to be underneath 111, and I dont seem to be able to do it with using absolute positioning ?

Comment: There's no 444 in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
flag=0;
displayhide(x){
a=document.getElementById(x).style;
if(flag=0)
    {
    a.display="block";
    flag=1;
    }
else
    {
    a.display="none";
    flag=0; 
    }
}
</script>

and use
<p><input type="button"  id="tg" onclick="displayhide('div2')" value="toggle"></p>
```

Comment: This may work, but it destroys the animation that jQuery provides and it's rather cumbersome.